# Design considerations for J2EE webapp on Tomcat in Amazon WebServices

Tags: java, tomcat, amazon-web-services, jakarta-ee, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My project is looking to deploy a new j2ee application to Amazon's cloud.  ElasticBeanstalk supports Tomcat apps, which seems perfect.  Are there any particular design considerations to keep in mind when writing said app that might differ from just a standalone tomcat on a server?

For example, I understand that the server is meant to scale automatically.  Is this like a cluster?  Our application framework tends to like to stick state in the HttpSession, is that a problem?  Or when it says it scales automatically, does that just mean memory and CPU?

Comment: You're deploying in a cloud, which means you should follow 12factor recomendations: http://12factor.net/.  They should be stateless, for starters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Automatic scaling on AWS is done via adding more servers, not adding more CPU/RAM. You can add more CPU/RAM manually, but it requires shutting down the server for a minute to make the change, and then configuring any software running on the server to take advantage of the added RAM, so that's not the way automatic scaling is done.

Elastic Beanstalk is basically a management interface for Amazon EC2 servers, Elastic Load Balancers and Auto Scaling Groups. It sets all that up for you and provides a convenient way of deploying new versions of your application easily. Elastic Beanstalk will create EC2 servers behind an Elastic Load Balancer and use an Auto Scaling configuration to add more servers as your application load increases. It handles adding the servers to the load balancer when they are ready to receive traffic, and removing them from the load balancer and deleting the extra servers when they are no longer needed.

For your Java application running on Tomcat you have a few options to handle horizontal scaling well. You can enable sticky sessions on the Load Balancer so that all requests from a specific user will go to the same server, thus keeping the HttpSession tied to the user. The main problem with this is that if a server is removed from the pool you may lose some HttpSessions and cause any users that were "stuck" to that server to be logged out of your application. The solution to this is to configure your Tomcat instances to store sessions in a shared location. There are Tomcat session store implementations out there that work with AWS services like ElastiCache ([Redis](https://github.com/jcoleman/tomcat-redis-session-manager)) and [DynamoDB](https://github.com/aws/aws-dynamodb-session-tomcat). I would recommend using one of those, probably the Redis implementation if you aren't already familiar with DynamoDB.

---

Another consideration for moving a Java application to AWS is that you cannot use any tools or libraries that rely on multi-cast. You may not be using multi-cast for anything, but in my experience every Java app I've had to migrate to AWS relied on multi-cast for clustering and I had to modify it to use a different clustering method.

Also, for a successful migration to AWS I suggest you read up a bit on VPCs, private IP versus public IP, and Security Groups. A solid understanding of those topics is key to setting up your network so that your web servers can communicate with your DB and cache servers in a secure and performant manner.